# remapping right click and drag as xbutton1 click and drag

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap right click and drag as XButton1 click and drag. This is what I tried:

RButtonclickdrag::XButton1clickdrag

I think I don't have the correct commands but I have searched a lot and not found anything else. Could somebody please give me some help?

Thanks,
Ellen

Comment: Did you try to find anything? A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=autohotkey+clickdrag) offers a lot of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this. Let me know if this suits your needs. The time is set to 100 ms.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

#ifWinActive ahk_class CorelDRAW 15.2
    $RButton::
        Sleep, 100
        GetKeyState, KeyState, RButton, p
        if KeyState = U
        {
            ;ToolTip, Short Press ; Activate to test behaviour
            Send, {RButton}
            Return
        }
        ;ToolTip, Long Press Started ; Activate to test behaviour
        sendmessage,0x111,0x1991d,0 ;pan one-shot
        MouseClick,L,,,1,0,D
        KeyWait, RButton
        ;ToolTip, Long Press Ended ; Activate to test behaviour
        MouseClick,L,,,1,0,U
    Return
#ifwinactive
```

Comment: Thank you. I definitely don't want to lose the right button at all; my goal was to keep the function of right click, which is used very frequently, while only remapping the right click and drag, which is used rarely. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: @decibelle, Might be possible. So when you click and let go, it should be the normal right mouse button action and when you click, hold and move the mouse, it should be Xbutton click, hold ad drag... Would a small delay for the normal right mouse button be a problem? Otherwise you would first get a "normal" right click (probably with a menu popping up) and only then cancelling the right click and switching over to the Xbutton behaviour...

Comment: That might be OK; I guess it depends on how long the delay would be.

Comment: @decibelle Does the example above help you?

Comment: Thank you. It's not working so I'll be more specific.

I'm using this code in CorelDRAW. 

#ifWinActive ahk_class CorelDRAW 15.2

XButton1::
sendmessage,0x111,0x1991d,0 ;pan one-shot
MouseClick,L,,,1,0,D
return
XButton1 up::MouseClick,L,,,1,0,U

#ifwinactive

Hand problems make it hard for me to use the thumb button. I realized that there is nothing here specifically about click and drag. I tried:

^!LButton::XButton1 works, but I need that for other things.

RButton::XButton1 works but disables right-click.

Can something be done here that to keep right-click but allow RButton click + drag?

Comment: Ellen, I have tried to combine your script with the Short/Long press script by me. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Robert,

You are a total hero. It is working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ellen, Glad to assist! Please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the WHITE "Check-mark" next to the answer, to turn it GREEN. Thank you! Clicking the check-mark will give credits to the person who submitted the answer and will mark the question as answered. See: [Accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)