# Emulate Hold Right Click = Hold Spacebar in Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Autohotkey)

Tags: photoshop, autohotkey

I've been trying to make an Autohotkey script to make a "hold-right-click" becomes the same function as "hold-spacebar" in adobe photoshop CS6, i've been so desperate for 1 day to find a solution for this but i can't , the only clue i have is this :
[remapping right click and drag as xbutton1 click and drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413471/remapping-right-click-and-drag-as-xbutton1-click-and-drag)

I've read it and i try to apply that in adobe photoshop CS6 but i've failed to do so, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Photoshop
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

$*RButton::
Sleep, 300
    GetKeyState, KeyState, RButton, p
    if KeyState = U
    {
        ;ToolTip, Short Press ; Activate to test behaviour
        Send, {RButton}
        Return
    }
    Send {Space Down}
MouseClick,L,,,1,0,D
    KeyWait, RButton
    Send {Space Up}
MouseClick,L,,,1,0,U
return
```

Comment: What is wrong with `RButton::Space`?

Comment: @Self if i do that i'd loose another function of right click,

Comment: No, you can still keep right click if you use tilde prefix.